# Fixing render function to allow Object with perspective projection

Tags: javascript, webgl, perspectivecamera

Im having troubles rendering my object after implementing perspective projection. Ive tried adjusting my shaders relative to the JS file, but im still not sure whats wrong. Any help would be highly appreciated! Also, the console isnt showing any errors, its only the rendering of the object that doesnt work.

```js
"use strict";

var canvas;
var gl;

var numVertices  = 36;

var texSize = 64;

var program;

var pointsArray = [];
var colorsArray = [];
var texCoordsArray = [];



//Images
var texture;

var texture2;


//Dimensions of Home

//Needed to multiply the length and the width by 5 b/c the rectangle was too small before hand

var l = 1
var h = .5 
var w = 1

//For Persepctive Distortion
var near = 0.3;
var far = 3.0;
var radius = 4.0;
var theta  = 0.0;
var phi    = 0.0;
var dr = 5.0 * Math.PI/180.0;

var  fovy = 45.0;  // Field-of-view in Y direction angle (in degrees)
var  aspect;       // Viewport aspect ratio

var mvMatrix, pMatrix;
var modelView, projection;
var eye;
const at = vec3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
const up = vec3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);



var texCoord = [
    vec2(0, 0),
    vec2(0, 1),
    vec2(1, 1),
    vec2(1, 0)
];

var vertices = [
   vec4( -l, -w,  h, 1.0 ),
   vec4( -l,  w,  h, 1.0 ),
   vec4( l,  w,  h, 1.0 ),
   vec4( l, -w,  h, 1.0 ),
   vec4( -l, -w, -h, 1.0 ),
   vec4( -l,  w, -h, 1.0 ),
   vec4( l,  w, -h, 1.0 ),
   vec4( l, -w, -h, 1.0 )


];



var vertexColors = [
    

    //Needed to set color to white inorder to for the images to be visable
    vec4( 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1 ),  // white
    vec4( 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 ),  // white
    vec4( 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 ),  // white
    vec4( 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 ),  // white
    vec4( 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 ),  // white
    vec4( 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 ),  // white
    vec4( 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 ),  // white
    vec4( 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 ),  // white

];

//For images

function configureTexture(image,image2) {
    
    //this is for picture of the wall
    
    texture = gl.createTexture();
    gl.bindTexture( gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture );
    gl.pixelStorei(gl.UNPACK_FLIP_Y_WEBGL, true);
    gl.texImage2D( gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGB, gl.RGB, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, image );
    gl.generateMipmap( gl.TEXTURE_2D );
    gl.texParameteri( gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST_MIPMAP_LINEAR );
    gl.texParameteri( gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST );
    gl.uniform1i(gl.getUniformLocation(program, "texture"), 0);


    //this is for picture of deques
    
    texture2 = gl.createTexture();
    gl.bindTexture( gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture2 );
    gl.pixelStorei(gl.UNPACK_FLIP_Y_WEBGL, true);
    gl.texImage2D( gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGB, gl.RGB, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, image2 );
    gl.generateMipmap( gl.TEXTURE_2D );
    gl.texParameteri( gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST_MIPMAP_LINEAR );
    gl.texParameteri( gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST );
    gl.uniform1i(gl.getUniformLocation(program, "texture2"), 0);
    

}


function quad(a, b, c, d) {


    //Lighting direction
    /*
    var t1 = subtract(vertices[b], vertices[a]);
    var t2 = subtract(vertices[c], vertices[b]);
    var normal = cross(t1, t2);
    var normal = vec3(normal);
    */


     pointsArray.push(vertices[a]);
     //normalsArray.push(normal);
     colorsArray.push(vertexColors[a]);
     texCoordsArray.push(texCoord[0]);

     pointsArray.push(vertices[b]);
     //normalsArray.push(normal);
     colorsArray.push(vertexColors[a]);
     texCoordsArray.push(texCoord[1]);

     pointsArray.push(vertices[c]);
     //normalsArray.push(normal);
     colorsArray.push(vertexColors[a]);
     texCoordsArray.push(texCoord[2]);

     pointsArray.push(vertices[a]);
     //normalsArray.push(normal);
     colorsArray.push(vertexColors[a]);
     texCoordsArray.push(texCoord[0]);

     pointsArray.push(vertices[c]);
     //normalsArray.push(normal);
     colorsArray.push(vertexColors[a]);
     texCoordsArray.push(texCoord[2]);

     pointsArray.push(vertices[d]);
     //normalsArray.push(normal);
     colorsArray.push(vertexColors[a]);
     texCoordsArray.push(texCoord[3]);
}


function colorCube()
{
    quad( 1, 0, 3, 2 );
    quad( 2, 3, 7, 6 );
    quad( 3, 0, 4, 7 );
    quad( 6, 5, 1, 2 );
    quad( 4, 5, 6, 7 );
    quad( 5, 4, 0, 1 );
}


window.onload = function init() {

    canvas = document.getElementById( "gl-canvas" );

    gl = WebGLUtils.setupWebGL( canvas );
    if ( !gl ) { alert( "WebGL isn't available" ); }

    gl.viewport( 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height );

    aspect =  canvas.width/canvas.height;

    
    //Set canvas to black
    gl.clearColor( 0, 0, 0, 1 );

    gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);

    //
    //  Load shaders and initialize attribute buffers
    //
    program = initShaders( gl, "vertex-shader", "fragment-shader" );
    gl.useProgram( program );

    colorCube();

    


    var cBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, cBuffer );
    gl.bufferData( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, flatten(colorsArray), gl.STATIC_DRAW );

    var vColor = gl.getAttribLocation( program, "vColor" );
    gl.vertexAttribPointer( vColor, 4, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0 );
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray( vColor );

    var vBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vBuffer );
    gl.bufferData( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, flatten(pointsArray), gl.STATIC_DRAW );

    var vPosition = gl.getAttribLocation( program, "vPosition" );
    gl.vertexAttribPointer( vPosition, 4, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0 );
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray( vPosition );

    var tBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, tBuffer );
    gl.bufferData( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, flatten(texCoordsArray), gl.STATIC_DRAW );

    var vTexCoord = gl.getAttribLocation( program, "vTexCoord" );
    gl.vertexAttribPointer( vTexCoord, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0 );
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray( vTexCoord );

    modelView = gl.getUniformLocation( program, "modelView" );
    projection = gl.getUniformLocation( program, "projection" );


    //Image of the wall (1) and deques (2)
    var image = document.getElementById("texImage");
    var image2 = document.getElementById("texImage2");
    configureTexture(image,image2);


    //Button to stop rotation
    document.getElementById("ButtonT").onclick = function(){flag = !flag};
    
    render();

}



var render = function(){
    
    gl.clear( gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    
    
    eye = vec3(radius*Math.sin(theta)*Math.cos(phi),
    radius*Math.sin(theta)*Math.sin(phi), radius*Math.cos(theta));
    mvMatrix = lookAt(eye, at , up);
    pMatrix = perspective(fovy, aspect, near, far);

    
    //Placing the image of deque on the larger face of the building
    gl.bindTexture( gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture2);
    gl.uniform1i(gl.getUniformLocation(program, "texture"), 0);
    gl.drawArrays( gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 6);


    //Wrapping the sides of the building with images of the wall
    
   gl.bindTexture( gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture );
   gl.uniform1i(gl.getUniformLocation(program, "texture"), 0);
   gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES,6,numVertices-6);
   

   gl.uniformMatrix4fv( modelView, false, flatten(mvMatrix) );
    gl.uniformMatrix4fv( projection, false, flatten(pMatrix) );
   


    
    requestAnimFrame(render);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style type="text/css">
    canvas { background: rgb(138, 40, 40); }
</style>
<script id="vertex-shader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">


attribute  vec4 vPosition;
attribute  vec4 vColor;
attribute  vec2 vTexCoord;

varying vec4 fColor;
varying vec2 fTexCoord;

uniform vec3 theta;

//lighting
uniform vec4 lightPosition;
uniform float shininess;
uniform vec4 diffuseProduct;
attribute  vec3 vNormal;

//For Persepctive Projection
uniform mat4 modelView;
uniform mat4 projection;

void main()
{

    fColor = vColor;
    fTexCoord = vTexCoord;
    gl_Position = projection * modelView * vPosition;
    gl_Position.z = -gl_Position.z;
}
</script>

<script id="fragment-shader" type="x-shader/x-fragment">

precision mediump float;

varying vec4 fColor;
varying  vec2 fTexCoord;

uniform sampler2D texture;


void
main()
{
   
    
    gl_FragColor = fColor * texture2D( texture, fTexCoord );
}
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="../Common/webgl-utils.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Common/initShaders.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Common/MV.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="FinalProject.js"></script>


<center>  <button id = "ButtonT">Toggle Rotation</button>   </center>
<body>

    <p> </p>
    <button id = "Button1">Increase Z</button>
    <button id = "Button2">Decrease Z</button>
    <button id = "Button3">Increase R</button>
    <button id = "Button4">Decrease R</button>
    
    <p> </p>
    <button id = "Button5">Increase theta</button>
    <button id = "Button6">Decrease theta</button>
    <button id = "Button7">Increase phi</button>
    <button id = "Button8">Decrease phi</button>
    <p> </p>



<center>  <canvas id="gl-canvas" width="600" height="512">
    Oops ... your browser doesn't support the HTML5 canvas element
    </canvas>       </center>

<center> Simplistic Model of the Dequés Building at GWU </center>

<center>---</center> 


<center> Ideas covered in this project: </center>

<center> Double Texture Mapping, Lighting </center>


    
<img id = "texImage" src = "brick copy.jpeg" hidden></img>
<img id = "texImage2" src = "house copy.jpg" hidden></img>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: from the code you posted the `perspective` and `lookAt` functions are not defined

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.